# Xbap Application - The download of the specified resource has failed, works in WebEx Session

Tags: internet-explorer, citrix, xbap, webex

A colleague has an issue with an xbap Application:
When accessing the URL, the following message appears

```
Startup URI: https://app.service.url/App.Client.xbap
Application Identity: 

The download of the specified resource has failed.
-----------------------
PresentationHost.exe v4.0.41210.0 built by: Main - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PresentationHost.exe
ntdll.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
kernel32.dll v6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432) - C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
....
```

When I set up a WebEx session and he enables Screensharing, the download succeeds and he can access the application. But as soon as he ends the screensharing, the download starts to fail again. A cleanup of the cache does not help via `rundll32 %windir%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache`
He is trying to access the application in a Citrix environment to have access to the company network.

I tried to find out which settings the WebEx Screensharing changes, but without success.

Here are a few details:

- IE 11.0.9600.18762
- Compatibility Mode: Enabled
- Access via https

Currently I am trying to get the application download to fail on my machine.
The things I have tried so far (but did not reproduce the error):

- I have read that WebEx changes the Protected Mode-Setting, so I enabled and restarted my machine
- Switch settings to disabled via "Settings -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level..."

Any input on how to tackle this issue, or the settings which are changed via WebEx screensharing would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Modify this GPO and you should be good to go:

User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\ Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Pages\Advanced Page\Do not save encrypted pages to disk.